# Create a new dataframe by removing the outliers from the column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, outliers

I am working on removing outlier tutorial but it quite confused me when this loop not working properly:

```py
target = df['ConvertedComp']
mean = target.mean()
sd = target.std()
for x in target:
    z_score = (x-mean)/sd
    if np.abs(z_score) > 3:
        selected_df = df[df.ConvertedComp != x]
```

Also are there any other method to create new dataframe without outlier efficiently ? Thank you ! Hope I can learn something new.

Comment: If I were to use your code as a basis, I would suggest that I create an empty list, add the following conditions, and then turn that list into a dataframe. `selected_df = []; selected_df.append(x)` There's also [this information](https://self-methods.com/pandas-quantile/) about the exclusion of outliers.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code to select rows where z_score calculated from `ConvertedComp` column is less than or equal to 3.

```py
mask = df['ConvertedComp'].sub(df['ConvertedComp'].mean()).div(df['ConvertedComp'].std()).abs().le(3)

df = df[mask]
```

Comment: Wow Im really unfamiliar with how to use sub() and le() like that. How interesting, but isnt it missing something ? you have to get x in df['ConvertedComp'] sub to median right ? Pls explain if you dont mind

Comment: Sorry Nvm I saw it

Comment: @duyquanduc Value operated on Series will be applied to every element in Series.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me.

*(NOTE: A variation of this answer by the course assistants is also available on the course's forum.)*

### Calculate the Lower quartile.

```
lower = d_q1-(1.5*IQR)

print("Lower: ", lower)
```

### Calculate the Upper quartile.

```
upper = d_q3+(1.5*IQR)

print("Upper: ", upper)
```

### Remove the lower & upper outliers by creating a new df.

```
df2 = [(df['ConvertedComp'] < lower) | (df['ConvertedComp'] > upper)]
```

### Change the outliers to "na" to remove their numerical data.

##### (That will leave them out of visualizations and value_counts().)

```
import numpy as np
df[df2] = np.nan
```